# Merge multiple incomplete records in SAS

Tags: merge, sas

I have a dataset, that each id has multiple incomplete records, it could make more sense to have a final dataset as shown. Basically the idea is to have non-missing data fill the blanks wherever the value is from the 1st line or 2nd line, as long as for the same id.

[image]

Comment: In the future, you should not attach your data as a picture, but instead as I did in my answer.  It makes it much easier to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is the self-update.  This uses the core property of the `update` statement, that only non-missing values can replace other values, in a fun way that allows the rows to be simplified like this.  The first `obs=0` is there simply to give an empty base to update from - the dataset is really being read in from the second mention on that statement.

```
data have;
 id = 1;
 input x y z;
datalines;
1 . .
. 1 .
. . 1
;;;;
run;

data want;
 update have(obs=0) have;
 by id;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

proc sql;
create table need as
Select ID, max(v1) as v1,
max(v2) as v2,
max(v3) as v3,
max(v4) as v4
from have;
quit;

Comment: Hi I just tried, some ID should have v1=0, but following your code, v1=1, which is the max among all IDs. Is there a way to select the MAX for each ID? besides, I have a second question: Could you suggest how can I count the appearance of each ID? In that example, I will also need a v5=3. (v5 can be 1 or 2 for other ids). Thank you!